# Exec as another user

Tags: go, exec

How to execute shell command with another user in GO, and get output from it ?

I tried:

```
cmd :=exec.Command("sudo","su",username, "-c",command)
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
CheckErr(err)
cmd.Run()
```

there is no output. anyone know how to do this?

Comment: does your user allowed to execute `sudo` without password ?

Comment: yes, both user (the 'username' and the one who run program) is on sudoer list

Comment: Being on the sudoers list is usually not enough. You would normally still need to supply a password. Programmatically, this will typically require `--prompt` and `--stdin` options be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the output of running the cmd.Run and also get your output using stdout is simpler than using the pipe.

```
cmd :=exec.Command("sudo","su",username, "-c",command)
cmd.Stderr = os.Stdout
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

err := cmd.Run()
CheckErr(err)
```

That should give you visibility of the error so you can find out what is occuring that prevents the sudo.

Comment: Thats progress, but unfortunately I am now out of my depth with `sudo`.  Does the command work if you type it in the shell?

Comment: I was just reading the man page (http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html) and I am wondering if it cant get the password for the user username when run from within a process?

Comment: @miltonb: sudo has the `-S` options to take a password on stdin.